# Iterate inserted in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

This SQL Server trigger works correctly for a single insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DebitSale]  
ON [dbo].[OrderDetails]  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS  
DECLARE @OrderId bigint
DECLARE @OrderNr int
DECLARE @TaxRate decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @Tax decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @Total decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @syncRate decimal(9,8)
DECLARE @Net decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @OldNet decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @ExactFee decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @Fee decimal(9,2) 
DECLARE @JobId bigint
DECLARE @ItemCode nvarchar(35)
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM inserted )
BEGIN
    SELECT  @syncRate = SyncRate
    FROM    dbo.[UserAccount]
    WHERE   Id = 0

    SELECT @Net = i.NrUnits * i.UnitNet from inserted i
    SELECT @OldNet = d.NrUnits * d.UnitNet from deleted d
    IF(@Net=@OldNet)
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END
    SELECT @OrderId = i.OrderId, @JobId = i.JobId, @ItemCode = i.ItemCode FROM inserted i
    SELECT @OrderNr = OrderNr, @TaxRate = TaxRate FROM Orders WHERE OrderId = @OrderId

    SET @Tax = @Net * @TaxRate / 100
    SET @Total = @Net + @Tax
    SET @ExactFee = @Total * @syncRate
    SET @Fee = FLOOR(@ExactFee * 100)/100

    IF(@Fee >= 0.01)
    BEGIN
    IF @JobId IS NULL
        INSERT INTO SubscriptionTransactions 
        (ItemValue, OrderNr, TransactionCredit, TransactionDate, TransactionDebit, TransactionDescription, TransactionType)
        VALUES (@Total, @OrderNr, 0, GetDate(), @Fee, @ItemCode, 'Item') 
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO SubscriptionTransactions 
        (ItemValue, OrderNr, TransactionCredit, TransactionDate, TransactionDebit, TransactionDescription, TransactionType)
        VALUES (@Total, @OrderNr, 0, GetDate(), @Fee, @ItemCode, 'Job') 
    END
END
```

However we sometimes get multiple rows in inserted so I included a loop like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DebitSale]  
ON [dbo].[OrderDetails]  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OrderId bigint
    DECLARE @OrderDetailId bigint
    DECLARE @OrderNr int
    DECLARE @TaxRate decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @Tax decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @Total decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @syncRate decimal(9,8)
    DECLARE @Net decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @OldNet decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @ExactFee decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @Fee decimal(9,2) 
    DECLARE @JobId bigint
    DECLARE @ItemCode nvarchar(35)

    SELECT  @syncRate = SyncRate
    FROM    dbo.[UserAccount]
    WHERE   Id = 0

    DECLARE @current INT = 0;
    DECLARE @InsertedCount int
    SELECT @InsertedCount =  Count(*) FROM inserted
    DECLARE @Thing nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @Thing ='InsertedCount ' + CAST(@InsertedCount AS VARCHAR)
    INSERT INTO DebugTable (DebugColumn) VALUES (@Thing)


    WHILE @current <= @InsertedCount
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Thing ='current ' + CAST(@current AS VARCHAR)
        INSERT INTO DebugTable (DebugColumn) VALUES (@Thing)
        SELECT @OrderDetailId AS OrderDetailId from inserted i
        ORDER BY OrderDetailId
        OFFSET @current ROWS   
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY  

        SET @current = @current + 1;
        SELECT @Net = NrUnits * UnitNet FROM inserted i WHERE i.OrderDetailId= @OrderDetailId
        SELECT @OldNet = d.NrUnits * d.UnitNet from deleted d where d.OrderDetailId= @OrderDetailId
        IF(@Net=@OldNet)
            CONTINUE 

        SELECT @OrderId = i.OrderId, @JobId = i.JobId, @ItemCode = i.ItemCode FROM inserted i WHERE i.OrderDetailId= @OrderDetailId
        SELECT @OrderNr = OrderNr, @TaxRate = TaxRate FROM Orders WHERE OrderId = @OrderId

        SET @Tax = @Net * @TaxRate / 100
        SET @Total = @Net + @Tax
        SET @ExactFee = @Total * @syncRate
        SET @Fee = FLOOR(@ExactFee * 100)/100
        IF(@Fee < 0.01)
            CONTINUE 

        IF (@JobId IS NULL)
            INSERT INTO SubscriptionTransactions 
            (ItemValue, OrderNr, TransactionCredit, TransactionDate, TransactionDebit, TransactionDescription, TransactionType)
            VALUES (@Total, @OrderNr, 0, GetDate(), @Fee, @ItemCode, 'Item') 
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO SubscriptionTransactions 
            (ItemValue, OrderNr, TransactionCredit, TransactionDate, TransactionDebit, TransactionDescription, TransactionType)
            VALUES (@Total, @OrderNr, 0, GetDate(), @Fee, @ItemCode, 'Job')
    END
    INSERT INTO DebugTable (DebugColumn) VALUES (@ItemCode)
END
```

This is a remote server that services a Web API. I don't have access to remote debugging so I've put some debug code in that logs a couple of lines to a DebugTable. The trigger writes to DebugTable if I execute an insert statement in SSMS, but doesn't update Transactions.

The Web API executes a merge statement in which case nothing is written to DebugTable and Transactions are not updated. I'm not sure if the new trigger is even firing.

I know there is a lot of TSQL here, but given the original trigger seems to work for a single insert, and that trigger is unchanged except for wrapping it in a loop, I assume I've got the loop wrong.

I expect some will spurn the loop, but in mitigation, there are rarely more than 2 rows inserted at a time.

How do I loop through inserted in a trigger?

Comment: You are selecting the rows from `inserted`, one by one, sending them all to the client. Then you select individual values from `inserted` and `deleted` without a `where` as if they contain one row each, which you know is not the case. Remove your loop, write one single joined query that calculates your variables as columns for each row, and insert from it into `SubscriptionTransactions`, you don't need the `if` either.

Comment: On average, you need a *loop* in an RDBMS about as often as Venus and Mars align, so whenever this appears as a solution it should raise an eyebrow.

Comment: @Stu [Venus and Mars align about once every year or two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(astronomy)#Average_interval_between_conjunctions) so you might be about right for a full-time DBA. A developer on the other hand should probably be around about a Neptune-Pluto conjuction :-)

Comment: @Charlieface I think it is safe to say the time frame of a Neptune-Pluto conjunction is about how frequently loops should used in a trigger...although that may actually still be a bit too common.

Answer (score 3):

Your main insert should be something like the following i.e. there is no need for a loop. One should always aim for set based operations in SQL if at all possible. The key points are:

- `JOIN` the relevant tables together
- use `CROSS APPLY` to avoid having to repeat calculations
- use the `WHERE` clause to exclude cases you are currently using `CONTINUE` for.

I've tried to match your logic as best I can. But without being able to test it I can't be sure it works. You will want to run it through a few tests to be sure its working exactly as you wish.

And I leave the debugging/logging code as an exercise for you.

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.SubscriptionTransactions (ItemValue, OrderNr, TransactionCredit, TransactionDate, TransactionDebit, TransactionDescription, TransactionType)
        SELECT
            T.Total
            , O.OrderNr
            , 0
            , GetDate()
            , F.Fee
            , I.ItemCode
            , CASE WHEN I.JobId IS NULL THEN 'Job' ELSE 'Item' END
        FROM Inserted I
        -- Deleted won't exist for an insert
        LEFT JOIN Deleted D on D.OrderDetailId = I.OrderDetailId
        INNER JOIN Orders O on O.OrderId = I.OrderId
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (I.NrUnits * I.UnitNet, D.NrUnits * D.UnitNet)
        ) N (Net, OldNet)
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (N.Net * (1.0 + N.Net * O.TaxRate / 100))
        ) T (Total)
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (FLOOR(T.Total * @SyncRate * 100)/100)
        ) F (Fee)
        WHERE (N.Net != N.OldNet OR D.OrderDetailId IS NULL) -- First continue condition
        AND Fee >= 0.01; -- Second continue condition
```

Comment: You missed the table alias for `JobId`

Comment: This is working better than my effort but the inserted values are incorrect. Where we have an order with 2 order details `ItemCode =19508 ItemNet=13.00 NrUnits=1` and  `ItemCode =19509 ItemNet=14.00 NrUnits=1` the values inserted in Trnsactions are ItemValue=29.90 and ItemValue=33.60 where each should be ItemNet+10%tax. ItemValue seems to accumulate. ItemValue seems to be close to SUM(ItemNet+10%tax).

Comment: @Vague There might be rounding errors, eg maybe you need to divide by `100.0`

Comment: You can simplify the whole `deleted` business to `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT N.Net EXCEPT SELECT D.NrUnits * D.UnitNet FROM deleted D WHERE D.OrderDetailId = I.OrderDetailId)`

Comment: @Vague you need to debug the query. 1) Create some temp tables #Inserted + #Deleted. 2) Put some relevant data in them. 3) Tweak the query above to use the temp tables with an insert and then work through the calculations so see at what point they diverge and then correct that.

Comment: @DaleK thank you for your effort but it is producing more than rounding errors. It appears to sum inserted then add tax and for the second row adds tax again. The query you propose is far too arcane for my pidgin sql to debug. We have a solution in production that works most of the time, so we'll stick with that for now. I remain open to solutions using sets or loops, my customers don't care how the problem is solved, they just want the right output.

Comment: @Vague honestly it shouldn't take much to get it working, its based on your original logic after all. And if you provided some test data DDL+DML (which should only take you a few minutes) I'd have a crack at getting it working.

Comment: Doesn't `FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`  mean I'm only joining on a single row from inserted?

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. I'm a goose for not seeing that. I've edited my question to filter inserted as suggested. Still doesn't work. The first debug output `SELECT @Thing ='InsertedCount ' + CAST(@InsertedCount AS VARCHAR)
    INSERT INTO DebugTable (DebugColumn) VALUES (@Thing)` doesn't insert anything

Comment: I don't think you are going to find anyone here who will help you get the loop working. Most people are going to give you a "best-practice" solution, which is what I have done i.e. no loops. If you had created the test tables with test data as I originally suggested you would have this solution working now instead of still trying to get the loop working.